# Not able to create object of thread class with parameters which are integers

Tags: c#, multithreading

Here I am not able to create thread class object for DisplayRange Method

What should I do,I Don't want to use object parameters inside DisplayRange

```
 public class Hello
 {
     public void DisplayRange(int iStart,int iEnd)
     {

     }
 }

public class Infosystems
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int iStart, iEnd;

        Hello mobs = new Hello();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(mobs.DisplayRange);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `mobs.DisplayRange`. Please add all relevant code

Comment: public class Hello
{
    public void DisplayRange(int iStart,int iEnd)
    {
        
    }
}

Comment: new class Hello contains the definition for DisplayRange

Comment: I Have edited the code

Comment: What error codes are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => mobs.DisplayRange(iStart, iEnd));
```

Comment: Sir can u explain what that syntax does